# 3D Python based simulation

Tags: python, 3d, simulation

I want model the flight of a couple of planes using path data. I want to make it so you can see the paths and play/pause as well as look around and interact with the environment. What open source python packages/programs can i use that will allow me to import the data and from that show the flight of the planes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could give more details of what you want, do you already have the 3D models? Do your paths are in geographical coordinates? With the information you provided, it seems you want a 3D engine.

For open source 3D display using Python I would suggest [Ogre 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) or [Panda 3D](http://www.panda3d.org/). The first is a 3D graphic rendering engine, the second is a 3D game engine.

And there is also [Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/), wich is a complete 3D software.

Keep in mind that working with 3 dimensions is always a hard task. For all the solutions above, you need time to learn and understand what is going on. I would recommend Blender for the models and Panda to get everything together and working (although Blender have a Game Engine, it is not as good as Panda).

Also, take a look at these [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755035/3d-engine-for-driving-simulation?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489377/what-are-good-libraries-for-creating-a-python-program-for-visually-appealing-3?rq=1).

Comment: I have data sets that give the geographical position of planes and the time at that point. Sorry I was not clear but I am just looking for something that I can use in which i can input the data(it's a large amount of data) through something python based and create a visual representation of the flight paths. I also want to be able to zoom in/out and look around while it is going. I just want to know what would be best to use to create this sumaltion of the flight data I have.